# Export excel in crystal report 8.5 not saving

Tags: vb6, export-to-excel, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a crystal report using with vb6. When I export to excel, it is automatically erasing in 2 seconds. Means when I click export excel save as windows is opening and saving in selected location but within 2 to 3 seconds it is deleting automatically. I have tried in many systems. But all other reports are working fine. Kindly help me out. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I don't the problem why it happened like that. What actually happened is we've migrated Oracle db from 9i to 11g. After migration some of the reports are unable to export which I've mentioned in issue.

I've opened the report and given db user, password and schema (Which already is there) and saved again. Now working fine.